# POST Request File Upload in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, httprequest

How to pass a file to perform file upload in Django Views by `POST` Request?
The File should be detected in `request.FILES`, and further shall be accepted by Model's `FileField` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST request with attached file can be sent using POSTMAN.

***1) Select:***
Select `POST` option from the drop-down list.

[image: Select POST option from the drop down list]

**2) Add File:** File can be added through the Body > Binary option. Choose the file to be sent.

[image: POSTMAN Attach File]

**3) Check Request object**

List of files sent to Django Server at `localhost:8000` can now be received by

> request.FILES

The Docs on request object can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/)

**4) Create Django File Object**

Further, to make the file acceptable by Django Model's FileField, it has to be in Django's File Object format.

```
from django.core.files import File

file_obj = open(path_to_file,"r")
django_file = File(file_obj)
```

This can be manually passed to Model's instance's FileField, and will be accepted. For more information on Django File Object, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/file/).